# How do I get started with contributing to the Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I want to start contributing to the Linux Kernel, plus I would like to, one day, fork the repository on github and add some modifications to it. How do I get started with contributing to the kernel? Is there something I should read/watch (I prefer watching videos). Is there some documentation that will hold my hand all the way through? Everything I've found hitherto hasn't been updated in a decade.

**My Background knowledge**:

I barely know a thing about operating systems. I know how to use the terminal, bash, etc, but that's about it. I know how to program in C, C++, Java, Python and JavaScript. I am learning Rust and have been wanting to learn x86 assembly, which I assume I will probably need in order to do something like this. I mainly use Windows and Mac, but have an Ubuntu Virtual Machine installed on my PC.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87898/how-to-learn-kernel-programming-from-the-start https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/how-to-build-my-own-kernel-where-should-i-start

Comment: @Kusalananda aren't the resources provided in the answers for those questions obsolete? They are from 7 years ago...

Comment: @Serket old information isn’t necessarily obsolete. The kernel development process hasn’t changed much overall in a long time.

Comment: @StephenKitt I was referring to understanding the OS more than understanding the development process in the question.

Comment: Looking at your other (and now recently closed) question I'm kind of getting the feeling you're not even remotely serious about this.

Comment: @Serket your question comes across as being about the contribution process, not about understanding the OS. Perhaps you could rephrase it to explain exactly what you want to find out.

Comment: I would start by contributing to another Free Software project. What other programs do you run on Gnu/Linux?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I use atom which I’m pretty sure is open source

Comment: Yes. If you are using a Gnu/Linux then it will be mostly [Free Software] (https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (Ubuntu, and some other distros, have some proprietary packages). However the base system (kernel, shell, shell-tools, core-libraries, windowing system) is Free Software. Linux the kernel is a small part, it is not a part that most user interact with, or that power users interact with most of the time. The kernel can be replaces and most people will not notice: see cygwin, WSL1, Gnu on BSD, Gnu on UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to start contributing to the Linux Kernel, plus I would like
> to, one day, fork the repository on github and add some modifications
> to it.

Linux kernel is not developed on Github
https://lwn.net/Articles/702177/. To contribute you need to send an
e-mail to mailing lists and individuals specified by
scripts/get_maintainer.pl

> How do I get started with contributing to the kernel? Is there
> something I should read/watch (I prefer watching videos). Is there
> some documentation that will hold my hand all the way through?
> Everything I've found hitherto hasn't been updated in a decade.

Start from reading files in Documentation/process directory in Linux
tree and watch this [Linux Kernel Development, Greg Kroah-Hartman -
Git Merge 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyenmLqJQjs) video. BTW,

> I prefer watching videos

Why? In order to contribute any significant change to Linux you'll
have to read a number of documents, mailing list threads, and
thousands lines of code.

> I mainly use Windows and Mac, but have an Ubuntu Virtual Machine
> installed on my PC.

In order to contribute a change to a huge and complex project that
Linux kernel is you have to have a thorough understanding of what
you're doing. Use Linux for a few years, learn how it works and find some
easy to fix bugs using `scripts/checkpatch.pl -f <file>`.

Comment: Why do people commit changes to github then? The repository is quite active and Linus Torvalds frequently makes changes...

Comment: Can the Documentation/process directory be found on github?

Comment: Github repository is just a mirror - see what KernelPRBot says under each PR: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/805

Comment: @Serket: yes, of course it can be https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/process but you have to know how to use git, too.

Comment: Don't worry, I use git on a daily basis :)